# List of All OAuth Errors?

Tags: oauth

Does Salesforce has a compiled list of all errors? (or at least those for the `OAuth` flow).

I'm currently working on a Salesforce app where I keep getting new kinds of errors from new users, I never know if the error is the server's problem or the client's problem. A list of all errors with there descriptions would really help my development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Salesforce responds to OAuth errors with Standard OAuth 2.0 error codes which can be found in the final version of the OAuth 2.0 spec: [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2).

In addition to the required `error` attribute, Salesforce will also generally provide the optional `error_description` attribute.

From the spec doc:

> ```
> error: A single ASCII [USASCII] error code from the following:
>
>    invalid_request
>          The request is missing a required parameter, includes an
>          unsupported parameter value (other than grant type),
>          repeats a parameter, includes multiple credentials,
>          utilizes more than one mechanism for authenticating the
>          client, or is otherwise malformed.
>
>    invalid_client
>          Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no
>          client authentication included, or unsupported
>          authentication method).  The authorization server MAY
>          return an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code to indicate
>          which HTTP authentication schemes are supported.  If the
>          client attempted to authenticate via the "Authorization"
>          request header field, the authorization server MUST
>          respond with an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code and
>          include the "WWW-Authenticate" response header field
>          matching the authentication scheme used by the client.
>
>    invalid_grant
>          The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
>          code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
>          invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
>          URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
>          another client.
>
>    unauthorized_client
>          The authenticated client is not authorized to use this
>          authorization grant type.
>
>    unsupported_grant_type
>          The authorization grant type is not supported by the
>          authorization server.
>
>    invalid_scope
>          The requested scope is invalid, unknown, malformed, or
>          exceeds the scope granted by the resource owner.
> ```